# Can't affect UITextView content with initWithCoder

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, iboutlet

I'm trying to get a string displayed in my `UITextView` the moment the app is launched.  I have a `UIView` and a `UITextView` in my interface, and one outlet, `myText`, which is connected to the `UITextView`.  It doesn't seem to be working and I can't say why....

Here is the code in question:

MainView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MainView : UIView {

    IBOutlet UITextView *myText;

}
@end
```

MainView.m

```
@implementation MainView

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {


    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"initWithCoder executed");
        myText.text = @"Hello, World!";
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

The `NSLog()` message is printed, so I assume that that `myText.text` is indeed set to `@"Hello World"`, but this isn't reflected in my `UITextView`.  Where is the hang up here?  If it helps, this is a simplified version of my actual app, and when I put that same `myText.text = @"Hello, World!";` into a method that responds to a button press, the change is reflected in the text view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nib connections are not necessarily there in `initWithCoder:` — just because this object has been unfrozen doesn't mean everything else in the nib has been. You want `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much!  Everybody here is amazingly helpful. As always, thanks for taking the time to help newbie!